# <VirtualHost> in XAMPP with multiples PHP versions

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, xampp, virtualhost

I've already posted a question recently about running multiple versions of PHP on XAMPP 7.4.16 server on Windows 10. At first it works OK and has no issues.
It's working like this:

**PHP 8 on port 8088**
**PHP 7.4 on port 80 (default)**
**PHP 7.3 on port 8083**
**PHP 7.2 on port 8082**
**PHP 7.1 on port 8081**
**PHP 7.0 on port 8080**
**PHP 5.6 on port 8056**

Now I need to create a VirtualHost to associate a domain to an application developed in Zend Framework and I'm not getting success. It was developed in PHP 5.6 and I need it to respond for the viderahome.local domain on the server.

**Here are my codes:**

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

**httpd-xampp.conf**

```
<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>


LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libsqlite3.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"


<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php7_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php7_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                 php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Virtual Hosts for run some PHP versions in specific ports

**PHP 8.0 in port 8088**

```
ScriptAlias /php_8.0 "C:/xampp/php_8.0"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php_8.0">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Listen 8088
<VirtualHost *:8088>
    UnsetEnv PHPRC
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        php_flag engine off
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php_8.0/php-cgi.exe"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**HP 7.3 in port 8083**

```
ScriptAlias /php_7.3 "C:/xampp/php_7.3"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php_7.3">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
        <Files "php-cgi.exe">
            Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

Listen 8083
<VirtualHost *:8083>
    UnsetEnv PHPRC
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        php_flag engine off
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php_7.3/php-cgi.exe"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**PHP 7.2 in port 8082**

```
ScriptAlias /php_7.2 "C:/xampp/php_7.2"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php_7.2">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
     Require all denied
     <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Listen 8082
<VirtualHost *:8082>
    UnsetEnv PHPRC
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        php_flag engine off
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php_7.2/php-cgi.exe"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**PHP 7.1 in port 8081**

```
ScriptAlias /php_7.1 "C:/xampp/php_7.1"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php_7.1">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    UnsetEnv PHPRC
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        php_flag engine off
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php_7.1/php-cgi.exe"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**PHP 7.0 in port 8080**

```
ScriptAlias /php_7.0 "C:/xampp/php_7.0"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php_7.0">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    UnsetEnv PHPRC
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        php_flag engine off
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php_7.0/php-cgi.exe"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**PHP 5.6 in port 8056**

```
ScriptAlias /php_5.6 "C:/xampp/php_5.6"

<IfModule actions_module>
    Action application/x-httpd-php56-cgi "/php_5.6/php-cgi.exe"
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/xampp/php_5.6">
    SetEnv PHPRC "C:/xampp/php_5.6"
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Listen 8056
<VirtualHost *:8056>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd-vhost.conf**

NameVirtualHost *

```
<VirtualHost viderahome.local:8056>
    DocumentRoot "D:\Dados\dados\htdocs\servicos\viderahome\www"
    ServerName viderahome.local
    ErrorLog "D:\Dados\dados\htdocs\servicos\viderahome\error.log"
    CustomLog "D:\Dados\dados\htdocs\servicos\viderahome\access.log" combined
    <Directory "D:\Dados\dados\htdocs\servicos\viderahome\www">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Hosts file**

C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 viderahome.local www.viderahome.local
```

**Logs**

### error.log

```
[Wed Jun 30 08:31:41.565771 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 8356:tid 2060] [client 127.0.0.1:60483] PHP Notice: compact(): Undefined variable: extras in D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\View\\Helper\\HeadLink.php on line 393
[Wed Jun 30 08:31:41.565898 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 8356:tid 2060] [client 127.0.0.1:60483] PHP Notice: compact(): Undefined variable: extras in D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\View\\Helper\\HeadLink.php on line 393
[Wed Jun 30 08:31:41.565898 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 8356:tid 2060] [client 127.0.0.1:60483] PHP Notice: compact(): Undefined variable: extras in D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\View\\Helper\\HeadLink.php on line 393
[Wed Jun 30 08:31:41.565898 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 8356:tid 2060] [client 127.0.0.1:60483] PHP Notice: compact(): Undefined variable: extras in D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\View\\Helper\\HeadLink.php on line 393
[Wed Jun 30 08:31:41.597514 2021] [php7:error] [pid 8356:tid 2060] [client 127.0.0.1:60483] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Session_Exception: Zend_Session::start() - D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\Session.php(Line:477): Error #2 session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /tmp) in D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\Session.php:490\nStack trace:\n#0 D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\application\\Bootstrap.php(84): Zend_Session::start()\n#1 D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\Application\\Bootstrap\\BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap->_initSession()\n#2 D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\Application\\Bootstrap\\BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('session')\n#3 D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\Application\\Bootstrap\\BootstrapAbstract.php(586): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap('session')\n#4 D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NU in D:\\Dados\\dados\\htdocs\\servicos\\viderahome\\library\\Zend\\Session.php on line 490
```

### access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2021:08:31:41 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
```

Every time I run in my browser the URL viderahome.local it points to the root of my web server and not to the Zend application folder.

What might be missing?

Best regards.

Ricardo.

Comment: Try breaking it down one step at a time, does it work with 2 ports, 3 etc. At what point is it breaking?

Comment: I found that the VirtualHost URL is working properly by adding the port number, that is, when I access: viderahome.local:8056 it accesses the application, but I am having a problem with the PHP version. Instead of accessing PHP 5.6 which responds to port 8056 it is accessing the default PHP of the XAMPP installation which is 7.4 on port 80. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a SetEnv at the top of the config file where the path to php is hard coded. Delete the environment variable defined here so that Apache will not override your Alias'